# How to use friendly_id in where case with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

I have two models: BigCategory and SmallCategory.

```
class BigCategory < ApplicationRecord
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged

  has_many :small_categories, dependent: :destroy
end

class SmallCategory < ApplicationRecord
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged

  belongs_to :big_category
end
```

I want to get all small_categories `where big_category_id == params[:big_category_id]`.

```
SmallCategory.where(big_category_id: params[:big_category_id])
```

The usage of friendly_id is `friendly.find`:

```
SmallCategory.friendly.find(params[:id])
```

Here `params[:id]` is the record id. So the above case. Is there a way to get all small_categories with beautiful url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way to do it all together would be to use a single [self-joining model](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins) to build a hierarchy:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: "Category"
  has_many :sub_categories, foreign_key: "parent_id", class_name: "Category"
end
```

If you then want to do a two level find you can do:

```
@parent = Category.includes(:sub_categories)
                  .find(params[:category_id])
@category = @parent.sub_categories
                   .friendly.find(params[:id])
```

Comment: Using a self join will let you build a hierarchy of any depth and also query for categories on the same table regardless of their "depth".